# VSTO in Excel: The customization does not have the required permissions to execute

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, vsto

At the very beginning.

Created a new Excel Workbook from VS2005. 
Try to save it? Cannot access the .xls file.
Try to run it? same error, plus the customization permissions error in the title.

Where do I set the permission?

EDIT

I've read a few SO questions and answers around this and it all seems terribly over-complicated. Give me a default security setting of open, let me download and install workthroughs to close it up, that's what I reckon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gacutil -i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\Addins\Msosec.dll"

caspol -m -ag LocalIntranet_Zone -url F:\dev* Nothing -n "my Folder" -d "my network development folder"

caspol -m -ag "My Code Group" -custom "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\Addins\Msosec.xml" FullTrust -n "Data Folder" -d "Grants FullTrust to all documents in my data folder"